# error trying to create extension: pg_stat_statement

Tags: installation, greenplum, pg-stat-statements

I'm trying to install pg_stat_statements doing this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

and I get this:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.10.1/share/postgresql/extension/pg_stat_statements.control": No such file or directory
```

I already installed postgresql-contrib as follow:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-contrib
```

The file pg_stat_statements.control is not found on the location specified in the error, should I download it? or how does it work?

Comment: If that even works with Greenplum, then I guess you have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation of that extension of greenplum. I would say its not supported.